# Or statement returns the first result only (should be 2)

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have an OR statement where the expected result should return 2 documents but the return result is only 1 document. I have a list of cars docs:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60a2c0621e5f043b735e36ef"),
    "car_id": 78,
    "terminal": "JFK",
    "timestamp": ISODate("2020-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"),
    
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60a2c0621e5f043b735e36f0"),
    "car_id": 78,
    "terminal": "LAX",
    "timestamp": ISODate("2020-02-08T17:00:00.000Z"),
    
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60a2c0621e5f043b735e36f1"),
    "car_id": 78,
    "terminal": "ORD",
    "timestamp": ISODate("2020-03-01T17:00:00.000Z"),
    
  },
]
```

and my query asks for 2 instances with SAME CAR ID but with DIFFERENT timestamp:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "car_id": 78,
          "timestamp": {
            "$lte": ISODate("2020-02-15T05:00:11.000Z")
          }
        },
        {
          "car_id": 78,
          "timestamp": {
            "$lte": ISODate("2020-03-02T11:07:27.000Z")
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "timestamp": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$car_id",
      "last": {
        "$last": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

So I expect to get 2 results (for each request).

Expected result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 78,
    "last": {
      "_id": ObjectId("60a2c0621e5f043b735e36f1"),
      "car_id": 78,
      "terminal": "ORD",
      "timestamp": ISODate("2020-03-01T17:00:00Z")
    }
  },

  {
    "_id": 78,
    "last": {
      "_id": ObjectId("60a2c0621e5f043b735e36f0"),
      "car_id": 78,
      "terminal": "LAX",
      "timestamp": ISODate("2020-02-08T17:00:00Z")
    }
  }
]
```

But I only get the first result. How can I get the desired 2 results?

[**mongoplayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RTBEYkuCFLA)

Comment: Dear ProcolHarum, it's recommended for the question to contain all necessary information in the question itself. Whilst mongoplayground is an amazing service and helps a lot it was not evident that you are also grouping results.

Comment: @AlexBlex ok got it. I see that you added it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because all of the returned docs has the same `car_id` and you use `car_id` in `$group` stage so they will be grouped into one result. To get your expected result, you can add a field depend on timestamp of the doc then use that filed in `$group`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "car_id": 78,
          "timestamp": {
            "$lte": ISODate("2020-02-15T05:00:11.000Z")
          }
        },
        {
          "car_id": 78,
          "timestamp": {
            "$lte": ISODate("2020-03-02T11:07:27.000Z")
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "timestamp": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      group: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $lte: [
              "$timestamp",
              ISODate("2020-02-15T05:00:11.000Z")
            ]
          },
          then: 1,
          else: 2
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$group",
      "last": {
        "$last": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T68pMK8S490)

**Note:** If you have more than one `car_id` in the result, you can change the `$group` to:

```
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      car_id: "$car_id",
      group: "$group",
    },
    "last": {
      "$last": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
}
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8j8rFaWMBuu)